# Pass hidden id to next page when click on a link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I have multiple control plane tables, each control plane belongs to a cluster.
When I clicked on any control plane, I will redirect to the control plane details page.
I need access to cluster id.

**Option 1: via route params**

I can get that bypassing it via the route like so

```
/deployments/bng/cluster/{clusterId}/services/{cp}
```

My first URL param will be `$clusterId` ... but my route structure like this

```
/deployments/bng/services/{cp}
```

**Option 2: via session**

I would have used `Session::put()` and `Session::get()`, but base on my index page, it doesn't seem to fit that.

**Option 3: via database ... store/query**
I find that too expensive, I rather not go this route.

**Option 4: via hidden input (HTTP POST)**
I would have done via hidden input if this is a form submit or ajax calls, but it is not...

Is there another way to pass on the clusterId to the next page?

[image]

Comment: If you can't modify the route like you want, why not tack on a GET param, eg: `/deployments/bng/services/{cp}?cluster={clusterId}`? That said, it's not terribly clear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think I might have to do what you suggest `GET param`

Comment: I have a restriction where I can't pass on via the route or session.

Comment: If you can't pass it as a URL param `/{cluser_id}`, or a `POST` param `cluster_id=...`, and you can't use `session()->put('cluster_id', ...)`/`session()->get('cluster_id')`, you might have to go the Database route; there are only so many ways to pass data between requests in Laravel/PHP. Sidenote, why is this restricted so much? Can you use something else to represent the Cluster, like `cluser_token` (which would be a random-generated "token" for each Cluster), or a `cluster_slug`, derived from the Cluster, etc etc. It feels like you're trying to dev this with one hand tied behind your back 